# How to write this summation equation in python

Tags: python-3.x, matlab

I have a summation equation and I code it in matlab. But I am not sure this is correct. So I want to write this summation equation using python. I didn.t have any idea how to write this summation code in python. Can anyone help me to correct this code?

Here when I plot it nothing display in graph.

[image]

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
n=0:24
for i=24
  f= sum(X(t))*(i)
end
vpa(sum(f))
plot(n,f)
```

plot graph:

[image]

```html
X(t)
10
20
30
50
60
80
90
150
160
170
180
```

After using  Nijin Koderi  code:

[image]

Comment: i fell like it should be `for i=1:24`

Comment: X(t) contains a value for each hour right ?

Comment: @Finn how could be it is 1:24 , can you explain it more ?

Comment: @Arthur yes. it is

Comment: So why does it only contain 11 values and not 24 ?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html?s_tid=doc_ta

Comment: @Arthur I didn't post whole column value . Sorry for my mistake

Comment: `for i=24` happens only once with `i=24`. the entire for loop is equal to  `sum(X(t))*24`

Comment: @ArthurThank you for helping me. I guess I got an answer with your help also

Comment: @Finn Thank you for the explanation and the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you try to achieve. Maybe you can help me understand your code?

Is your problem that you don't know how to re-write your equation (given in MATLAB) in python or do you not succeed plotting the equation? Actually, the snippet given can't be plotted.

- What's the value of t?
- Second what are you trying to achieve with the line?

```matlab
for i=24
  f=sum(X)*(i)
end
```

**(1)** This is like writing :

```matlab
i=24
f=sum(X()*(i)
```

You will get a scalar value.
The result in both cases will be `f = 41040`.

**(2)** If you want to receive a vector you can just multiply both values:

```matlab
n=0:24
f=sum(X)*n
```

This will return the vector `f = [ 0 1710 3420 ... ]`.

- In the next line you sum you vector `X(t)`, which is in your case is *1710*. Then you multiply it 24 times, but always assign it to the same variable (the previous value will get overwritten).
  Because of your line `vpa(sum(f))` I assume you expect a vector **(2)**, not a scalar. I have explained it above. 
  By the way: This line doesn't make sense to me. Assuming you meant **(2)**, you will again receive a scalar value, but you do not assign it to a variable.

---

I have rewritten your code so it makes sense to me. If I plot this, I will receive a ramp.

```matlab
clc;
clear all;
X=10:10:180
n=0:24
f=sum(X)*n
vpa(sum(f)) % What’s the purpose?
plot(n,f)
```

Comment: great explanation. Thank you very much. Here t is in every one hour measured value of X and here I just post subset of x value. for  vpn(sum(f)) for final answer for all the summation. putting for loop is not matching for this summation, after reading it I got it. Thank you very much. This help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
clc;
clear all;
n=0:24
X=[10,20,30,50,60,80,90,150,160,170,180]
for i=24
f= sum(X)*(i)
end
plot(n,f)
```

[image]

**Try this**

Comment: Thank you very much for trying and helping me to solve it, but still no graph is showing

Comment: Welcome on SO ! Have you tested the code ? It is not working at all.